# As a letter / character may have color? like this: ✔️

Tags: ascii

I have found this letter / character in facebook, but how can this have a color? is just insane for me, look this: ✔️

---

Added image (From Firefox on windows)
[image]

Comment: What colour? Where? Provide a screenshot of what you're talking about, at the very least. I doubt it's really related to programming anyway.

Comment: `<span style="color: pink">✔️</span>`.

Comment: @MarcB I don't believe Facebook posts/comments can use HTML to format colors/fonts.

Comment: @alroc: then perhaps OP should actually explain where/how this char comes from. "from facebook" is about as useful as saying "seen on planet earth".

Answer (score 2):

It's not an ASCII character, it's likely an [emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji). Emoji are part of Unicode and the actual glyph displayed to the user is open to interpretation by the platform displaying it. The spec suggests a name/description, but the implementation varies.

So while you may see a colored check mark, I see black & white. Other times, a single glyph will have multiple styles made available on a particular platform; for example, I can select multiple "skin" tones when I use a smiley face on my iPhone, but your Android device may only show a generic one.

Edit: The image edited into the original post is a perfect example. Using Chrome on Windows, I see a black check mark. The screenshot from Firefox shows green.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols used here aren't ascii-encoded. They use the much more vast range of Unicode encoding. Ascii(extended) is restricted to a 256 symbol set.

The unicode interpretation for symbols/glyphs(small pictorial representation)(these ticks aren't characters), can vary for different platforms as some the range of unicode is open for usage and isn't set as global.

Which is why, while the unicode encryption remains the same for every device irrespective, the decryption is differently interpreted by different devices/online-platforms, allowing us to perceive either a coloured or a black symbol.